Popup newsletter flashing once in homepage
I've got a problem with simple popup newsletter in homepage...
Basically after I close the popup, if I refresh homepage, popup appears for about one second then disappear.
This is the code:
  function popup(){
    $('.jsclosepoup').on('click', function() {
      $('.jsengo_popup').addClass('d-none');

    });
  }

<section class="popup jsengo_popup">
    <div class="modal-window">
      <div class="window-window">
        <div class="window-content clearfix">
          <a class="close_edit jsclosepoup" title="Close" href="javascript:void(0)">ù
              Something useful for Newsletter...
          </a>
        </div>
      </div> 
    </div>
</section>

It seems that class "d-none" be applied only after all html loaded.
I would like to prevent newsletter appears for a second if I already close it....

"It seems that class "d-none" be applied only after all html loaded" - but not by the code you have shown us so far - because that only applies the class when you click the link. Anything that would store the info, that the popup was closed, so that it can be hidden automatically again on the next page load, you have not even shown us yet.

Better to do this the other way around - have the element hidden by default, and then show it on page load, if you don't find the info, that it was already previously closed, in whatever location you have actually stored that.

Here the complete code I've found:
      function popup(){
    $('.jsclosepoup').on('click', function() {
      $('.jsengo_popup').addClass('d-none');

    });
  }
  function cookiepopup(){
    if (!jQuery.cookie('brilliant_pop_newletter') || jQuery.cookie('brilliant_pop_newletter') == null) {    
      jQuery(window).on('load', function() {
        setTimeout($('.jsengo_popup').show(), 300 * 1000);
        jQuery('.jsclosepoup').click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          jQuery('.jsengo_popup').hide(); 
          jQuery.cookie('brilliant_pop_newletter', '1', {expires: 1, path:'/', domain: '{{shop.url}}' });
                                                        });
        });
      } else {
             $('.jsengo_popup').remove();
    }
}


While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now.

Just semplified code, but still appears for a little moment...
I don't want appears again after closed...
function popup() {
    if (!jQuery.cookie('brilliant_pop_newletter') || 
        jQuery.cookie('brilliant_pop_newletter') == null) {
            $('.jsclosepoup').on('click', function() {
                jQuery.cookie('brilliant_pop_newletter', '1', {expires: 1, path:'/', domain: '{{shop.url}}' });
            $('.jsengo_popup').hide();
        });
    } else {
        $('.jsengo_popup').hide();
    }
}

